# How to restrict user to select image below 500kb from gallery?

Tags: android, bitmap, gallery

I need too display a image in ImageView and upload to server by fetching from gallery. I have got a problem that I should allow the user to send image file more than 500kb. How to restrict the user to choose below 500kb. Or is there any way to compress the Image to PNG format which I got form Uri.  Please need a solution
My Code follows:

```
if(requestCode == Constants.SELECT_PICTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
if(data != null)
{
photoUri = data.getData();
if (photoUri != null)
{
try {
bMap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), photoUri);
Bitmap bitMap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bMap, 320, 480, false);
cabinImge.setImageBitmap(bitMap);
Utility.releaseImgViewMemory(cabinImge);
uploadImage(bitMap);
}catch(OutOfMemoryError e){ 
e.printStackTrace();
}catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}                       
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you select an image from the gallery in your app, it will return a URI for that image.  You can then retrive its size and apply calculation on that simply `byte/1024`